# CameraX ImageCapture with SDK api level less than 24

Tags: android-broadcast, android-camerax

I am concerned about ImageCapture use case of cameraX with api level less than 24 where the official basic example code of onImageSaved block looks like this:

```
// Implicit broadcasts will be ignored for devices running API level >= 24
// so if you only target API level 24+ you can remove this statement
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   requireActivity().sendBroadcast(
      Intent(android.hardware.Camera.ACTION_NEW_PICTURE, savedUri)
   )
}
```

- android.hardware.Camera is deprecated in SDK api level 21.
- CameraX works on SDK api level 21+.

Is this deprecated piece of code realy necessary as the comment implies, and if so, how should the recieving end look like?

*CameraX official basic example CameraFragment:*
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/main/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt#L416